# Theme:Changing the borders and the dividers of the context menu?

Tags: android

I think my question is self explanatory. I managed to change the color of context menu by using

```
</style>
     <style name="GradientLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
     <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/listView</item>
     <item name="android:itemBackground">#999999</item>
</style>
```

in the `styles` XML, but I am unable to change it's divider.

Here is the image that I am trying to change.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:divider">#F00</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
</style>
```